# Access inbox/messages from Facebook account using api v2.6 still possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using v2.6 of Facebook API, trying the requests in GraphAPI interface. My goal is to get the messages from the account but i always receive this error message:

```
"error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (messages) on node type (User)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "DdRsSIGtBNX"
  }
```

This is the url.. me/messages. Below is a screenshot of the permissions that i selected when creating the access token used in the request.
[image]

I know this was possible in the older versions, but I am not sure anymore if we can do it now with the last version(everytime i select a method from the Facebook docs it does not take into consideration the api already chosen and i think this is confusing). Does anyone know if getting messages/conversation still possible with v2.6? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible any more to get access to a user’s messages - that has been removed with API v2.4

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_deprecations

Comment: Are there any alternatives to read a users messenger conversations?

Comment: @MarkStokes only the ones they would be having with a page/page bot of yours.